# Excel Auto increment to set value and reset to intial value

Tags: excel

I have a tray which holds 20 parts, each part is weighed individually and I need gross mass of all parts. I have a formulae for SI No,Validation, Tray number and Autosum. I am having trouble resetting auto increment to initial value in excel.

Columns:

Raw mass    Mass    SI No   Validation  Tray number Gross mass
1st column (Raw mass) of the part

2nd column (mass good part) stores the mass of part

3rd column - if there is a good part data in column 2. it increments the number of good parts unto 20. then it should reset to 1 (I am unable to reset to 1 it is incrementing to 21 as can be shown in the attached image) 
formulae:

```
=IF(INDIRECT("A"&ROW())="","",COUNTA($A$2:INDIRECT("A"&ROW()-1))+1)
```

3rd column (SI No) add count of good parts

4th column (Validation) when the count reaches "20" I set the validation to be true.
Formula
    =IF(B21=20,TRUE,"")

5th column- when the tray is full. in the next row new tray number is added

Formula:

```
=IF(INDIRECT("C"&ROW()-1)=TRUE,"Tray "&COUNTIF($C$1:C22,"TRUE")+1,"")
```

6th column- when the parts count reaches 20. gross mass is calculated

Formulae:

```
=IF(INDIRECT("C"&ROW())=TRUE, SUM(INDIRECT(("A"&ROW()-20)):INDIRECT("A"&ROW())),"")
```

Thanks for the responses. I want to record gross mass of each trays, each trays contains 20 good parts.

Each part is weighed and the raw data is stored in if it is within limits it will be added to the tray if not rejected. with the current table I am able to get the first tray mass 1-20. in the next row (21st) and so on I want repeat the numbers from 1-20 again.[Data Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bqVd.png)

Can you please guide to dynamically reset the parts count to 1 if it reaches 20. or is there any better way of doing these calculations

Comment: Please post some sample data, together with current actual and expected results

Comment: It seems like there is a better way to do this, but it's hard to tell from just the formulas alone. Can you give an example of what kind of an output you are expecting vs. what you are getting?